# Dynamic link creation dependency is not supporting in android

Tags: android, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using firebase to read data attached with dynamic link but but it showing the compile time error. My APP level gradle is given below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.bitstreet.com.itdwallet"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        // Add the following two lines

        renderscriptTargetApi 18

        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile project(':pinentry')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'

    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:1.8'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.4.0'


   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.4.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

//for fire base pushnotification
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and the code which i am adding the below code inside onCreate() in my SplashscreenActivity.java , It is showing error **Can not resolve symbol FirebaseDynamicLinks and PendingDynamicLinkData**

```
 FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
                .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                        // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                        Uri deepLink = null;
                        if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                            deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                            String data = deepLink.getQueryParameter("data");
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                    }
                });
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You're on a pretty old version of the SDK! Try updating to 11.8.0 wherever you have 9.4.0 (for both Firebase and Google Play Services). Its worth noting App Invites moved to Firebase Invites, so you can drop your dependency on `com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite`.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.8.0'
// Delete  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.4.0'
```